# Ubuntu 16.04 - Sources.list Problem

Tags: 16.04, software-sources, error-handling

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.02 a couple of minutes ago. When I want to update my system:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Ubuntu does not update itself. The error message is above:

[error list](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25025974/)

The problem is with sources.list. But how can i solve this problem? Please help me!

Comment: try this list generator https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ . back up your current sources.list file then replace the contents with what the list generator gives

Answer (score 0):

Seems your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is broken..

Usually your it should look somehow like (at least for my Ubuntu Servers its looks like this)

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonicals
## "partner" repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:
disable any ppa.
disable ipv6 for now ,
run: sudo service resolvconf restart ,
run sudo apt update first

if that doesn't fix it, then you may want to try using a mirror from software & update -> Ubuntu Software - Download from -> other -> select the best server.